# How to make StopWatch in QT c++?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm making an app on QT with UI. Also, I have a function. I want to display the running time of a function. I also want to pause the stopwatch. Any ideas on how to properly embed a stopwatch in my application?
Here is my code:

```
void SomeFunc()
{
while (1)
{
// Start Timer
// some code
// Stop Timer
// Start Timer2
// some code
// Stop Timer2
}
}

on_push_button()
{
auto futureWatcher = new QFutureWatcher<void>(this);
    QObject::connect(futureWatcher, &QFutureWatcher<void>::finished, futureWatcher, &QFutureWatcher<void>::deleteLater);
    auto future = QtConcurrent::run( [=]{ PackBytes( file_path, file_name, isProgressBar); });

    futureWatcher->setFuture(future);
}
```

Comment: I think you should use [QTimer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html)

Comment: if I use a QTimer, I will have to process the function 100 times per second via a signal. I don't think it's good.

Comment: by "stopwatch", you mean you want to track how long the computation in "PackBytes" is already running, right? by "pausing", do you mean the computation should also be stopped, or do you only want the time to stop...?

Comment: You probably want [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qelapsedtimer.html](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qelapsedtimer.html)

Comment: Does "display" in this context mean "show an animated elapsed-time value in a GUI widget while the function is executing", or does it mean "print the total time it took for the function to executed to stdout after the function has returned"?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I mean to show an animated elapsed-time value in a GUI widget while the function is executing

Comment: @codeling Yes, by 'stopwatch' I mean to track how long the computation in "PackBytes" is already running, and by "pausing" I mean the only stopwatch to stop

Comment: @РостиславРоманец  does the provided answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`QElapsedTimer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qelapsedtimer.html) for measuring the duration since starting the computation.
Judging from [your previous questions on very related topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71862558/ui-blocks-while-the-program-is-running-in-qt-c), you do have a `MainWindow` class that contains the `on_push_button` function. In that class, declare the `QElapsedTimer` member; then [start](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qelapsedtimer.html#start) it when your computation starts.

Use a [`QTimer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html) to update the GUI element you use for displaying the current duration (only needs to run once a second or so).

Example code:

in your header file:

```cpp
#include <QElapsedTimer>
#include <QTimer>
//...

class MainWindow
{
    // ... other stuff you have
private:
    QTimer m_stopwatchUpdate;
    QElapsedTimer m_stopwatchElapsed;
};
```

in your cpp file:

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_push_button()
{
    // ideally do this once only in the constructor of MainWindow:
    connect(&m_stopwatchUpdate, &QTimer::timeout, this, [=]{
        //.. update GUI elements here...
    });
    auto futureWatcher = new QFutureWatcher<void>(this);
    connect(futureWatcher, &QFutureWatcher<void>::finished, futureWatcher, &QFutureWatcher<void>::deleteLater);
    auto future = QtConcurrent::run( [=]{
        m_stopwatchElapsed.start();
        PackBytes(file_path, file_name, isProgressBar);
    });
    m_stopwatchUpdate.start(1000);
    futureWatcher->setFuture(future);
}
```